# Troubles with computing/understanding resultant

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to compute 
$$
R\left(a\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)x+b, x^{n-1}+\frac{a}{n}\right)
$$
I think the result $\left(\frac{-b}{a}\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}+\frac{a}{n}$ because $R(f,g) = \prod_{x:f(x) = 0}g(x)$(?).
But wolfram mathematica says that it's not.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $f(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = 0$ in your example. This would result in $\frac an$ as $R(f,g)$ with $f(x) = a(1-1/n)x$ and $g(x) = x^{n-1} + a/n$

Comment: @AlexR i'm sorry, i have forgot $+b$

Comment: What result does Mathematica give you then? Because if your definition of resultant is correct and the functions are correct, your result is.

Comment: Actually the correct definition seems to be
$$R(f,g)  = \prod_{x : f(x) = 0} \prod_{y : g(y) = 0} x-y$$
In your special case we get
$$R(f,g) = -\frac ba \frac n{n-1} - \sqrt[n-1]{-\frac an}$$
For $n$ even and for $n$ odd
$$R(f,g) = (-\frac ba \frac n{n-1} - \sqrt[n-1]{-\frac an})(-\frac ba \frac n{n-1} + \sqrt[n-1]{-\frac an})$$
if $-\frac an > 0$.